# Jupyter Notebook Launch Error from Navigator

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

When I attempt to launch Jupyter NB from Anaconda Navigator, nothing happens, and in the terminal I see the following:

```
/home/captroberts/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/notebook.sh: 5: /home/captroberts/anaconda3/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate-gxx_linux-64.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

What does this mean, how do I fix it to launch apps from Navigator.

Jupyter-Notebook from the shell works fine.

Comment: Is that all the output?

Comment: Affirmative, that is all.

Comment: I have the same issue, additionally also spyder is not launching from anaconda navigator.

Comment: @riyansh.legend I also had this issue. eSab's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu by default the interpreting shell is dash.
set **bash** as the **/bin/sh**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue for me. I'm in Debian, but same idea. The default shell was dash, and changing it to bash gets rid of the error. When I typed in the above command, I got an interactive screen in the terminal asking if I wanted to set dash as the default shell interpreter. I said no, and now my interpreter is bash. Restarting Anaconda-Navigator, I get Jupyter notebook opening again.

Answer (score 5):

The following fixed the issue for me. Some suggestion online to remove the word 'function' from line 5 and 31 from all the .sh files in the folders anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d and anaconda3/etc/conda/deactivate.d

Comment: I recommend using eSab's answer if you want to avoid changing your anaconda configuration files.

Answer (score 2):

I just started deleting the offending *.sh files until it worked.  No issues since.

Comment: eSab's answer will solve the issue without deleting any configuration files. Those files may have other useful things in them, and deleting them could break other parts of anaconda.